# gnuplot - how to get colored text in label with epslatex terminal

Tags: latex, gnuplot, figure

I have a complex figure made with an epslatex terminal in gnuplot. It is a multiplot figure with four panels. In each panel I draw three curves (for three different values of a parameter) and then I superimpose another curve for another parameter on top of each curve. 
I can distinguish the first parameter with different types of points, and the second one with color.

So, I use the key to distinguish the different points and I would need to have another kind of key for the two colors. Then I use a label with colored text. The point is, the text does not get colored in the epslatex terminal!

I have

> set terminal epslatex color solid 8

and

> set label 10 'H' tc lt 1 at 0.01,6

This way I get the 'H' label in black. If I use

> set terminal epslatex color colortext solid 8

it gives me the error

> Package color not loaded in conjunction with terminal option `colourtext'.

Any idea what's the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `\texcolor` command, provided by `color` package.  If you use `standalone` mode `color` package is automatically loaded with `color` option to terminal, otherwise you have to explicitly load `color` (or `xcolor`) package in your LaTeX document.

A colorful example:

```
set terminal epslatex color solid 8 standalone
set output "foo.tex"
set format x '$\textcolor{green}{%g}$'
set format y '$\textcolor{yellow}{%g}$'
set label 10 '\textcolor{blue}{H}' at 0.01,6
plot x**3 title '$\textcolor{magenta}{x}^{\textcolor{cyan}{3}}$'
set output
```

Result:

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

Using the `colortext` option works, but as the error message says, you must include the `color` package in your document. If you use the `standalone` option, this is done automatically. So the following works fine:

```
set terminal epslatex color colortext standalone
set output 'foo.tex'
set label 'lt 1' tc lt 1 at graph 0.2,0.5
set label 'blue' tc rgb 'blue' at graph 0.7,0.5
plot x
```

There is no need to use the `\textcolor` macro explicitely unless you want different colors in one label.

Comment: Awesome, without `color` and with `textcolor` options I did get colored lines, but not colored labels. I did not get the errormessage though.

Comment: Thanks @Chrisoph !